# From performance perspective, what is more advantageuos?

Tags: jquery, performance

From performance perspective, what is more advantageuos ?

1) Call Jquery externally

or

2) Storing Jquery on our server

Comment: 1..........................................................but performance of what?

Comment: Our Website performance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bigger question is the usage issue.

If you are planning to update your code on a regular basis then link externally so you will always be using the latest version of Jquery. This does mean if the API changes and you don't bother to update your code then it may well break.

If you want to be sure your site will work until you update it then store the version you are using on your own server. That way, even if the Jquery API changes, your site will still work fine.

Answer (score 0):

- How fast and wide is your CDN?
- Faster than localized Google/etc servers?
- How often do you change what you're deploying?
- Is it a custom deploy?
- Do you have other processes/transforms acting on what you're serving?

In other words, this question is impossible to answer as-is, and it should be *obvious* it isn't possible to answer it as-is. The amount of information necessary to provide an objective, "correct" answer is a lot.